# How to design an api for nested child component of react js select options

Tags: reactjs, api, multidimensional-array, contextmenu, api-design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU7o2.png)
how can i design the api that can help me do CRUD operation.

I want to get the value from every column. But i am facing problem for the select option and input values. I want to edit them also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.